# How to edit an item using GridView widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

, I'm working at GridView in flutter but I need to just change layout for one item or some items not the all, like (height or width..etc) .
childAspectRatio option it also change all items so this is the issue I need to change specific items that I choose so how I can do that ? .

code :

```
class StaggeredGridExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StaggeredGridExampleState createState() => _StaggeredGridExampleState();
}

class _StaggeredGridExampleState extends State<StaggeredGridExample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      childAspectRatio: 16/9,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Icon(Icons.translate),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          child: Icon(Icons.shop),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          child: Icon(Icons.date_range),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.cyan,
          child: Icon(Icons.radio),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.brown,
          child: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

gridview requires all items to be the same size. If you want to customize and use different sizes, you need to use a plugin.

url link : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view